# Unable to parse RuboCop response in Rubymine 2019.3

Tags: bundler, rubymine, rubocop

Rubymine reports that it's unable to parse the output from rubocop in my project.

[image]

When I click the details link, this is what it shows:

```
Error:Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 68 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
{"metadata":{"rubocop_version":"0.80.1","ruby_engine":"ruby","ruby_version":"2.6.3","ruby_patchlevel":"62","ruby_platform":"x86_64-darwin18"},"files":[{"path":"db/seeds.rb","offenses":[{"severity":"convention","message":"Missing frozen string literal comment.","cop_name":"Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment","corrected":false,"correctable":true,"location":{"start_line":1,"start_column":1,"last_line":1,"last_column":1,"length":1,"line":1,"column":1}},{"severity":"convention","message":"Line is too long. [103/80]","cop_name":"Layout/LineLength","corrected":false,"correctable":true,"location":{"start_line":1,"start_column":81,"last_line":1,"last_column":103,"length":23,"line":1,"column":81}},{"severity":"convention","message":"Line is too long. [111/80]","cop_name":"Layout/LineLength","corrected":false,"correctable":true,"location":{"start_line":2,"start_column":81,"last_line":2 ...
```

I'm assuming the problem is related to the extra bundler output that is getting parsed, in addition to the JSON. Any ideas of how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have any additional script that has the output about the bundler?

Comment: No, this is the only context where I get this output. It seems like they are running some kind of bundle update every time.

Comment: Do you get the same output in case you run RuboCop from the Terminal? The normal output usually doesn't contain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people say if you upgrade Rubocop to 0.88 or later, it fixes. I tested myself and can confirm.

See the discussion: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-26861